# LESS nested interpolation

Tags: css, less, interpolation

I'm trying to generate a css file that will contain definitions of multiple themes, but I'm having trouble getting LESS to compile it the way I want it. It seems that I need a second interpolation of the value I get, and I'm not sure there's even a way to achieve what I'm trying.

---

Here's what I've got so far:

```
@all-themes: pastel, antique, hipster;

@pastel-background: #a7b3a5;
@pastel-primary: #b4bdc0;

@antique-background: #856357;
@antique-primary: #eae3ea;

@hipster-background: #1a2930;
@hipster-primary: #f7ce3e;

.generate-themes(@i:1) when (@i <= length(@all-themes)) {
    @theme-name: extract(@all-themes, @i);
    @background: ~'@@{theme-name}-background';
    @primary: ~'@@{theme-name}-primary';

    body.theme-@{theme-name} {
        background-color: @background;
        color: @primary;
    }

    // ... more definitions ...

    .generate-themes(@i + 1);
}

// call the mixin
.generate-themes();
```

---

I'm expecting it to generate the following:

```
body.theme-pastel {
    background-color: #a7b3a5;
    color: #b4bdc0;
}

body.theme-antique {
    background-color: #856357;
    color: #eae3ea;
}

body.theme-hipster {
    background-color: #1a2930;
    color: #f7ce3e;
}
```

---

However, what I'm getting in my css is this:

```
body.theme-pastel {
    background-color: @pastel-background;
    color: @pastel-primary;
}

body.theme-antique {
    background-color: @antique-background;
    color: @antique-primary;
}

body.theme-hipster {
    background-color: @hipster-background;
    color: @hipster-primary;
}
```

...which is obviously not working. Is there any good way to get a 'double interpolation'?

Comment: You need to use it like `~'@{@{theme-name}-background}'` instead of `~'@@{theme-name}-background'`. Without the second set of `{}`, the `@{theme-name}` will get recognized by compiler as a variable and will be substituted with the value but the rest (the `@` at start and `-background` at end) of it is just string concatenation. The compiler will not further evaluate the variable because it hasn't been told to so. So, you will only get output like `@pastel-background` etc. That said, your workaround looks much cleaner than the snippet in question.

Comment: @Harry if you'd like to post your comment as an answer, I will be happy to select it as the correct one. Although I did end up refactoring my less to the format of my workaround, your answer does provide a way to do nested interpolation and does answer the original inquiry.

Comment: Would surely do. I am away from my PC right now. Will do in an hour or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** The alternate approach used in your answer looks more cleaner and better to me. It could possibly be improved further but that's beyond the scope of this answer. I am posting this answer only to show what was wrong with the code in question.

As I had mentioned in my comment, the standard syntax for selector or property interpolation is `@{}`. Only when this syntax is encountered the compiler realizes that it must evaluate a variable with same name and substitute its value. For the following statement:

```
@background: ~'@@{theme-name}-background';
```

the below are the steps that the compiler would perform:

- As soon as it encounters `@{theme-name}`, it knows that the value of the variable should be put in there and so replaces it with pastel or antique or hipster.
- Now we can assume the compiler to see the above statement as `~'@pastel-background'`. Since there are no further `{}` wrappers, the compiler sees it as just another string and leaves it as-is.

If there was another wrapper (like `~'@{pastel-background}'`), the compiler will see it as yet another variable which has to be evaluated, look for a variable named `pastel-background` and use its value.

```
@all-themes: pastel, antique, hipster;

@pastel-background: #a7b3a5;
@pastel-primary: #b4bdc0;

@antique-background: #856357;
@antique-primary: #eae3ea;

@hipster-background: #1a2930;
@hipster-primary: #f7ce3e;

.generate-themes(@i:1) when (@i <= length(@all-themes)) {
  @theme-name: extract(@all-themes, @i);
  @background: ~'@{@{theme-name}-background}';
  @primary: ~'@{@{theme-name}-primary}';

    body.theme-@{theme-name} {
        background-color: @background;
        color: @primary;
    }

    // ... more definitions ...

    .generate-themes(@i + 1);
}

// call the mixin
.generate-themes();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround, unless someone can provide a better solution:

```
@pastel-theme: #a7b3a5, #b4bdc0;
@antique-theme: #856357, #eae3ea;
@hipster-theme: #1a2930, #f7ce3e;

@all-themes: pastel @pastel-theme, antique @antique-theme, hipster @hipster-theme;

.generate-themes(@i:1) when (@i <= length(@all-themes)) {
    @theme-pair: extract(@all-themes, @i);
    @theme-name: extract(@theme-pair, 1);
    @theme-def: extract(@theme-pair, 2);
    @background: extract(@theme-def, 1);
    @primary: extract(@theme-def, 2);

    body.theme-@{theme-name} {
        background-color: @background;
        color: @primary;
    }

    // ... more definitions ...

    .generate-themes(@i + 1);
}

// call the mixin
.generate-themes();
```